# Close menu without clicking on the X

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

https://jsfiddle.net/aristyros/15ejzko0/

Attached is a link to the code I'm working with. I'm a beginner and I've tried to use all the logic I can muster reading other answers on "how to close menu when clicking outside box" but I just can't get it to work. Does it have something to do with my JS or the fact that my toggle button doesn't have an onclick event? I know this questions been asked 1000s of times but none of those solutions helped me (perhaps if I understood it better they would.)

```
var navTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-trigger')[0],
              body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

          navTrigger.addEventListener('click', toggleNavigation);

          function toggleNavigation(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           body.classList.toggle('nav-open');
          }
```

Comment: This should help :)
`var  overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay'); overlay.addEventListener('click', toggleNavigation);`

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ykpws60g/6/

Comment: Wow @GrzegorzT. that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listener to the hamburger ad the overlay and then verify what you clicked on.

```js
const navTrigger = document.querySelector('.nav-trigger');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

navTrigger.addEventListener('click', toggleNavigation, false);
document.body.addEventListener('click', toggleNavigation, false);

function toggleNavigation(event) {
  if (event.target === navTrigger || event.target.parentNode === navTrigger) {
    let isOpen = document.body.classList.contains('nav-open');
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open', !isOpen);
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  } else if (event.target === overlay)  {
    if (document.body.classList.contains('nav-open')) {
      document.body.classList.remove('nav-open');
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.nav-trigger {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 55px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: 100%;
}

.nav-trigger span,
.nav-trigger span::before,
.nav-trigger span::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  width: 36px;
  background: #999999;
}

.nav-trigger span {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: background .3s;
}

.nav-trigger span::before,
.nav-trigger span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: background .3s, transform .3s;
}

.nav-trigger span::before {
  transform: translateY(-12px);
}

.nav-trigger span::after {
  transform: translateY(12px);
}

.nav-trigger:hover span,
.nav-trigger:hover span::before,
.nav-trigger:hover span::after {
  background: white;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span {
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span::before,
.nav-open .nav-trigger span::after {
  background: #1F2B3D;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger:hover span::before,
.nav-open .nav-trigger:hover span::after {
  background: #D00;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1C1D21;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
}

.nav-open .overlay {
  opacity: .6;
  visibility: visible;
}

.nav-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 460px;
  padding: 2em 3.5em;
  background: #F3F3F3;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.07, .23, .34, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-open .nav-container {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav-container h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: helvetica neue;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #AAAAAA;
  background-color: #0187fa;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.hamburger {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

@media and screen (min-width: 300px) {
  #hamburgernav a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

#hamburgernav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: helvetica neue;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.nav-open .nav a {
  animation: slide-in .4s .2s backwards;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(2) a {
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(3) a {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(4) a {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(5) a {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#navigation" class="nav-trigger">Menu<span></span></a>
<div class="nav-container" id="navigation">
  <ul class="hamburger" id="hamburgernav">
    <li><a href="login.html">login</a></li>
    <li><a href="analyze.html">analyze my film</a></li>
    <li><a href="schedule.html">festival strategy</a></li>
    <li><a href="findfests.html">find fests</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```